# Rows matched but changed 0

Tags: mariadb, query

I have been scratching my head for hours.

Query matches but nothing is updated. Mariadb 10.6.

```
UPDATE field_data_field_coupon_description 
SET field_coupon_description_value = 'Limited time only Discount.' 
WHERE field_coupon_description_value LIKE '%Enter the price at checkout.%';
```

matches example row but doesn't change it.

`Enter the price at checkout. Ends on 14/11/2021.`

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.668 sec)
Rows matched: 18133  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: Maybe, a trigger? https://dbfiddle.uk/XqY65xqk

Comment: Yes - thanks a lot mate. Much appreciated.